# pygtk - how update a gtk.liststore?

Tags: python, pygtk

http://img824.imageshack.us/i/capturadetelag.png/

how update a gtk.liststore?

i mean get a random number every second on a column just like example,
such as a download manager list, i'd like to have a simple example to know how this Liststore
works for update the list, because i can't find a effective way to do something like a:

store.append(list1,list2,list3)

store.update(list3,['foobar']).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can iterate over the rows in a list store (`for row in liststore:...`) as well as over the columns (values) in each row (`for col_value in row:...`).

For simple, direct updates:

```
row_n = 0
col_n = 2
liststore[row_n][col_n] = 'new value'
```

Otherwise, you can update using a `gtk.TreeIter` (`row_iter`):

```
liststore.set_value(row_iter, col_n, 'new value')
```

Answer (score 4):

[gtk.ListStore](https://web.archive.org/web/20100706173649/http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkliststore.html)

You need to use a [gtk.TreeIter](https://web.archive.org/web/20100706174150/http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtktreeiter.html), also [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20100617130213/http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-TreeModelInterface.html) has some good information.

If I were more familiar I could give you an example, I just remember that it's kind of a pain to use the gtk.liststore, but there's not really any better solution